# Is GDB capable of changing (JLE to JGE)?

Tags: gdb, reverse-engineering

Is GDB capable of changing certain program tasks? such as from "jle"(Jump less than or equal to) to "jge"(jump greater than or equal to).

from: `0x0000000000400563 <+45>:    jle    0x400547 <main+17>`

to: `0x0000000000400563 <+45>:    jge    0x400547 <main+17>`

Answer (score 0):

> Is GDB capable of changing memory arithmetics?

What is "memory arithmetic"?

> such as from "jle"(Jump less than or equal to) to "jge"(jump greater than or equal to).

Your question is exceedingly unclear. I *think* you are asking: can I change a program to perform `JGE` instead of current `JLE` instruction in GDB?

If that is your question, the answer is yes.

1. Find the opcode that is currently being used with `disas/r 0x400563,0x400564` command.
2. Change the opcode to that of `JGE` with an assignment to the instruction opcode.

Example:

```
(gdb) disas/r 0x400496,0x400497
Dump of assembler code from 0x400496 to 0x400497:
   0x0000000000400496 <main(int, char**)+15>:   7e 07   jle    0x40049f <main(int, char**)+24>
End of assembler dump.
```

The opcode is `0x7E`. The opcode for `JGE` is `0x7D` ([table](http://faydoc.tripod.com/cpu/jle.htm)).

Let's patch. You can do that for a running process:

```
(gdb) start
(gdb) set *(char*)0x400496 = 0x7d
(gdb) disas/r 0x400496,0x400497


Dump of assembler code from 0x400496 to 0x400497:
   0x0000000000400496 <main(int, char**)+15>:   7d 07   jge    0x40049f <main(int, char**)+24>
End of assembler dump.
```

Or you can update the binary on disk, but invoking `gdb --write a.out`.